# How to set BaseClass variable from DerivedClass parameter

Tags: c++, class, derived-class

I have the classes Player and HumanPlayer. HumanPlayer is derived from Player.

```
class Player {
private:
    int id;
protected:
    string name;
public:
    Player(int id);
    ~Player();
}

class HumanPlayer : public Player {
public:
    HumanPlayer(int id, string name);
}
```

I want to make a constructor for HumanPlayer the set the Player id and name but I don't seem to figure out how to set Player::id to the HumanPlayer::id.

This is what I have worked out but gives an error
*"int Player::id' is private within this context"*

```
HumanPlayer::HumanPlayer(int id, string name) : Player(id){
    this -> id = id;
    this -> name = name;
}
```

Comment: Remove this statement this -> id = id;. It is redundant. The constructor of the base class already set this data member.

Comment: The error speaks for itself, `id` is private. But you don't need to assign to it, since `: Player(id)` already sets it.

Comment: This is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72353673/how-to-add-variable-to-derived-initialization-list-from-base-class-initializatio), but still similar enough that it's striking that both were asked within hours of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your understanding.

```
class Player {
private:
    int id;
protected:
    std::string name;
public:

    //Base class constructor, initialize Id.
    Player(int i):id(i)
    {}

    ~Player() {}

    //Test
    int GetId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    std::string GetName()
    {
        return name;
    }
};

class HumanPlayer : public Player {
public:
    HumanPlayer(int i, std::string s) :Player(i) //Pass on Id  base class constructor
    {
        name = s; //Protected variable accessible.
    }
};

void main()
{
    HumanPlayer hPlayer(10, "Test");

    std::cout << hPlayer.GetId() << std::endl;
    std::cout << hPlayer.GetName() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot. I didn't understand that the id parameter of the derived class was passed to the base class when you call the HumanPlayer constructor.

Comment: If you don't want to benefit from upvotes, you can make your answer a community wiki.